# Shorthand to avoid falsy 0 value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a server response that sends back an object like so:

```
{
 success: integer
}
```

On the client, I have

```
return body && body.success;
```

the problem is that the integer might be zero, in which case the above would return `body` instead of `body.success`.

What is the best shorthand I can use to always return the value?

Comment: It would return the number value in any case. "in which case the above would return `body.success` instead of `body.success[0]`." --- that's not true.

Comment: @plalx sorry I don't follow what you are saying

Comment: I simplified the question, I think it's easier to understand now, thanks

Comment: "in which case the above would return body instead of body.success." --- it still is not true. Any chance you tried it before making up?

Comment: `body` will never be the result of that, unless `body` is *falsey* - and in the original version of the question, even an empty array is truthy, so the original version would always result in `success[0]`

Comment: this question should be closed, false premise, sorry all

Comment: @AlexanderMills You should be able to delete your own question, no? Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

You should always initialize your property in the back end. I would set as "-1".

```js
function ajaxCall() { 
  return { success: true, id: 10 }; 
  //return null; 
}

function GetData() {
  var myData = ajaxCall();

  if (typeof myData === "undefined" 
  || myData == null 
  || typeof myData.success === "undefined" 
  || myData.success == null) {
    return { success: false, id: 0 };
  } 

  return myData;
}

var body = GetData();

// init
(function(){
 document.getElementById("MyMessage").innerHTML = ((body.success) ? "Success - " + body.id : "Failed") ;
})();
```

```html
<div id="MyMessage"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work:

```
return body && (typeof body.success !== "undefined" ? body.success : false);
```

The parenthesis may be incorrect, but this should check is body defined? If so, is body.success defined? If not return body.

If body.success is defined, return body.success. If not,  return body.

It could be written this way:

```
If (body)
    return (typeof body.success !== "undefined" ? body.success : body);
else return false;
```

Comment: note, the question asks for `the best shorthand` - and while your code is technically correct, the best shorthand would be, `return body && body.success;` - though, you're now editing it to make it longhand and redundant

Comment: More `typeof` checks for the god of the typeof checks!